# Access Backbone model in sync callback

Tags: backbone.js

I'm passing a `_model` to my `ProcessModel` function then in my ProcessModel function it will save the model to the server which in return triggers `sync` event. What I want to do is in my `sync` callback access `_model` because `CartView` is listening for add or change event from my `_model`. Am I making any sense?

```
var _cartItem  = this.ConvertToSaleItem(item);
_cartItem.on('sync', this.TaxChangeSaveSuccess,  this);
_cartItem.on('error', this.TaxChangeSaveError, this);

_cartItem.url = Global.ServiceUrl + Service.SOP + Method.SALEITEMTAX;
_cartItem.save();
```

My Callback :

```
TaxChangeSaveSuccess : function(model, response, options) {
    if(!Global.isBrowserMode) window.plugins.cbNetworkActivity.HideIndicator();
        item.set({
            SalesTaxAmountRate : model.get("SalesTaxAmountRate")
        }); 
    },
```

But item is undefined. Any ideas on how to do it? I need the same model for my views to catch any events triggered from my model which is item.

Comment: is the item variable available at a higher scope?

Comment: nope. I tried making item variable available at a higher scope but still it doesn't trigger any events which my views are listening to.

Comment: `this.TaxChangeSaveSuccess` is this code inside of your view, because this can be done `initialize:function(){ this.model.on("sync",callback,context); }`

Answer (score 0):

Two options immediately come to mind:

1. Store `item` as a property on your `this`.
2. Do it by hand with an anonymous function wrapper.

The first one would look like this:

```
this.item = item;
_cartItem.on('sync', this.TaxChangeSaveSuccess,  this);

//...

TaxChangeSaveSuccess : function(model, response, options) {
    if(!Global.isBrowserMode) window.plugins.cbNetworkActivity.HideIndicator();
        this.item.set({
            SalesTaxAmountRate : model.get("SalesTaxAmountRate")
        });
```

The second would look like something like this:

```
_cartItem.on('sync', _(function(model, response, options) {
    this.TaxChangeSaveSuccess(model, response, options, item);
})).bind(this));

//...

TaxChangeSaveSuccess : function(model, response, options, item) {
    // Same stuff you have already
```

You could also use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) to supply `item` to the callback function using `bind`'s partial application features. There are other ways to set up the wrapper, I'm just going for something simple and easy to understand here.

Which one works better for you depends on your specific circumstances.